# Display 20 records per page in SSRS report

Tags: group-by, dataset, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to make an ssrs report show 20 rows per page and I've tried using

```
=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/20)
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK.

My rows contain a field that counts a number so it's just making that one field equal 20 for each page. Is there any way to make the tablix object only print a set number of rows per page so it's not reliant on the group by of the dataset?

I've also tried changing that 'nothing' to a field in the dataset but that throws an error.

Here's how my report tablix is set up:

```
| Part | Part Description |   Part Qty   | Part Weight |  Total Weight   |

|[Part]|[Part Description]|[SUM(PartQty)]|[Part Weight]|[SUM(TotalWeight)]
```

What I expect to get with the =Ceiling expression:

```
| Part | Part Description |   Part Qty   | Part Weight |  Total Weight   |

|PART1 |Part 1 Desc       |12             |5.00        |[60.00]
|PART2 |Part 2 Desc       |3              |5.00        |[15.00]
|PART3 |Part 3 Desc       |5              |5.00        |[25.00]
|PART4 |Part 4 Desc       |7              |5.00        |[35.00]
```

...Continue until 20 rows then page break

This is what I'm getting:

```
| Part | Part Description |   Part Qty   | Part Weight |  Total Weight   |

|PART1 |Part 1 Desc       |12            |5.00         |[60.00]
|PART2 |Part 2 Desc       |3             |5.00         |[15.00]
|PART3 |Part 3 Desc       |5             |5.00         |[25.00]
--Page Break
|PART4 |Part 4 Desc       |7             |5.00         |[35.00]
```

The field PartQty will count up to equal 20 then a page break.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Add a new row group and the the "group on" option to `=CEILING(RowNumber(nothing)/20)`. This group should be the outermost group so if you only had a details group you could right click the details group and choose "add group => parent group"
2. Delete the new column if one was just created - we don't need this.
3. Right-click the new row group you created in hte row gorup panel at the bottom of the screen and click 'Properties'
4. In the "Page Breaks" section, set the option to 'Between each instance of a group'

**Note:** Whilst this will do what you want be aware that it won't actually set the number of rows per page, it sets the number of rows per group and then puts a break between each group. If you set the value in CEILING to 100 for instance, each group probably go over several pages.

Comment: That doesn't work. What happens is it takes the one field that has a number in it and just prints enough rows to make that one field equal 20 then do another page so the first page has 2 rows, with the field showing 16 then 4.

Comment: The steps above should not have any effect on any existing columns or values, not does it require anything existing in your report. The 'paging' group should have nothing other than what is described above. If you are still struggling, please edit your question and show you report design, some sample data and what you are getting as output now. I've just tested my answer and it works as expected.

Comment: There is a group by that was on the report that was needed but I've tried doing the same with that group by removed, added, changed, included in the =ceiling expression. Every combination of using that expression I have tried and it does not work. There has to be another way to make a tablix show 20 rows, page break and show the next 20

Comment: Please show a screen shot of the report design and screen shots of any existing groups including an image of the row groups panel. It looks like you are grouping on PART but I need to be sure. Once I have this info I'll update the answer.

Comment: I was grouping on part, when I took all groups away and then did the above code it worked but not exactly. Since there was no longer a group on parts it would show as PartQty 1 and 20 entries of that which means that the parts were duplicated. It seems there's no way to make a report limit it's rows if you have a number in the fields.

Comment: You probably can but it's messy and slow, you have to count the distinct number of groups as a running total and group on that. You might find it easier if you do your part grouping in SQL, then you can use the simple CEILING method.

Comment: I do have a grouping on my sql side. The report ignores it and forces it to spread all parts out to only qty 1 per row.

Comment: As i don't know what your base data or query looks like I can only guess, but you only seem to be grouping by part, description and weight to get an aggregate of qty. Surely you can do this in the dataset so that the report does not need any grouping on part, then use the Ceiling method

Comment: My sql query is something like this: with cte as (select 3 tables of data) select user, partnumber, count(partqty) as partqty, partdesc, partweight. There are other fields for the rest of the report but it doesn't matter if they're there or not. Then we group by user, partnumber, partqty, partdesc, partweight order by partnumber asc. Data result in sql has all parts listed with a total qty. Data result in report has all parts listed multiple times with partqty 1 until total has been reached and they are out of order, the first 3 are part1, then 7 part 2, then another 3 of part1.

Comment: By the way I do appreciate your help and I wish I had more to come back with than "it just doesn't work" but my work requires a bit of confidentiality so there's not much more I can say other than giving examples of what's happening. I've also been working on this issue that seemed really simple for about 14 hours now and I'm very frustrated.